# Using mate desktop without systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, mate-desktop

I am using Debian Jessie with the Mate desktop and I would like to remove systemd from my system. I am following [these](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation) instructions but as soon as I enter

```
apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove systemd
```

`apt-get` lists the mate desktop packages `mate-desktop-environment`, etc as packages to be removed.
I knew that Gnome 3 had a dependency on systemd but I thought Mate hadn't: I got Mate running fine on FreeBSD, obviously without systemd.

Am I doing something wrong, or otherwise are there perhaps alternative Mate packages for Debian that do not rely on systemd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer was accurate when it was written, in 2016, for Jessie. I don’t know what the situation is in current releases of Debian.)

You should be able to run MATE without using systemd as your system's init, but as it stands in Debian currently you need to have the `systemd` package installed, because `mate-desktop-environment` ends up depending on `libpam-systemd` which depends on `systemd`. To use all this alongside `sysvinit` (or Upstart) you need to install `systemd-shim` instead of `systemd-sysv`.

Comment: I have already installed `systemd-shim`, and `systemd-sysv` is not installed. I wanted to remove `systemd` to free up some space but it seems it is not possible. Thanks for the useful information.

Comment: As far as I understand, it should be possible to remove this dependency. Mate does not require systemd on other distributions, see e.g. the FAQ at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/MATE

Comment: The Gentoo MATE FAQ says you don't need to *run* systemd to use MATE, which is also the case on Debian. The dependency on the `systemd` package comes via `gvfs`, but it's only an installation dependency, not a runtime dependency. You could always rebuild `gvfs` to drop the `libpam-systemd` requirement. (This would be equivalent to what you'd go through on Gentoo...)

Comment: I had understood that it doesn't need systemd to run. I meant that the indirect dependency can be removed. Thanks a lot for pointing at `gvfs`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `systemd-shim` is no longer in Debian unstable. elogind should make the process more bearable but I still think it requires rebuilding the debian package with some tweaks.